# How to sum up for each distinct value c in array X all elements Y[i] where X[i] = k efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an 1D array `X` of length `n` in Numpy with `k` distinct values, I want to sum up for each of these distinct values `c` in another 1D array `Y` with the same length, all those elements `Y[idx]` where `X[idx] == c` in the most efficient way.

Example:

`X = [1, 3, 2, 1, 2]` and `Y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 2.0, 0.3]`. The length `n` is 5 and we have `k=3` distinct values in `X`. That means that the result of our operation is a vector of the `k=3` distinct elements `[1, 3, 2]` in `X` and the corresponding sums from the elements of `Y` which is `[2.1, 0.2, 0.8]`. It's also fine if the distinct elements are ordered. Thus `[1, 2, 3]` with `[2.1, 0.8, 0.2]` would also be a solution.

I have already looked up various functions in Numpy and the closest to what I want is `np.unique(X, return_counts=True)` but it returns the counts and not the sums in Y.

One could, of course, solve the whole thing with a nasty loop like:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 3, 2, 1, 2])
Y = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 2.0, 0.3])

def unique_sums(x, y):
    distinct_x = np.unique(x)
    y_sums = np.empty(distinct_x.shape)
    for idx, val in enumerate(distinct_x):
        y_sums[idx] = np.sum(y[x == val])
    return distinct_x, y_sums

unique_sums(X, Y)
```

leading to the ordered result:

```
(array([1, 2, 3]), array([2.1, 0.8, 0.2]))
```

Is there a vectorized operation like this in Numpy or any other common Python library? If not, what would be the most efficient implementation in Cython?

Comment: Can you post somewhere how the posted approaches fair on your hinted  ~10k to ~100k sized datasets? I am guessing performance i.e. runtime is your priority, so it would be nice to see how these stack up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
In [21]: u, inv = np.unique(X, return_inverse=True)                                                                                                            

In [22]: sums = np.zeros(len(u), dtype=Y.dtype)                                                                                                                               

In [23]: np.add.at(sums, inv, Y)                                                                                                                               

In [24]: sums                                                                                                                                                  
Out[24]: array([2.1, 0.8, 0.2])
```

This replaces your `for`-loop with the nifty method `numpy.add.at`.

Note that `np.unique` sorts `X`, so this method is O(n*log(n)).  That's not the best possible time complexity for this problem.

Comment: I am really impressed! Exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of these `ufunc.at` functions in Numpy.

Answer (score 2):

We will try to leverage `pandas.factorize` to efficiently get unique int-based IDs and then use `numpy.bincount` to get ID based summing. So, the solution would look something like this -

```
import pandas as pd

def unique_sums_factorize_bincount(X, Y):
    ids,unq = pd.factorize(X)
    return unq, np.bincount(ids,Y)
```

Sample run -

```
In [24]: X = np.array([ 1,   3,   2,   1,   2]).astype(float)
    ...: Y = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 2.0, 0.3])

In [25]: unique_sums_factorize_bincount(X,Y)
Out[25]: (array([1., 3., 2.]), array([2.1, 0.2, 0.8]))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` here for a more efficient solution

---

***Setup***

```
X = np.array([1, 3, 2, 1, 2])
Y = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 2.0, 0.3])
```

---

```
from scipy import sparse

res = sparse.csr_matrix(
    (Y, X, np.arange(Y.shape[0]+1)),
    (Y.shape[0], X.max()+1)
).sum(0).A1
```

```
array([0. , 2.1, 0.8, 0.2])
```

This is a list of sums from `0 -> k`, where `k` is the maximum value of your `X` array.  Any entry where a key does not exist in `X` will obviously be `0`.  To get a better mapping back, you can use `np.unique` and some indexing:

```
u = np.unique(X)
np.column_stack((u, res[u]))
```

```
array([[1. , 2.1],
       [2. , 0.8],
       [3. , 0.2]])
```

---

***Timings***

```
X = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100_000)
Y = np.random.rand(100_000)

In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: sparse.csr_matrix(
    ...:     (Y, X, np.arange(Y.shape[0]+1)),
    ...:     (Y.shape[0], X.max()+1)
    ...: ).sum(0).A1
    ...:
1.15 ms ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: u, inv = np.unique(X, return_inverse=True)
    ...: sums = np.zeros(len(u), dtype=Y.dtype)
    ...: np.add.at(sums, inv, Y)
    ...:
16.5 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit unique_sums(X, Y)
16.6 ms ± 169 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks, smart idea. Do I also get the corresponding list of distinct values in your solution?

Comment: No, you do not.  If you need those, you'll have to use `np.unique`.  However, based on my timings, using `np.unique` doesn't add enough overhead to make any of the other solutions faster than this one.  For example, with `n=100_000`, it adds about 3ms to the total time, resulting in still being 3x faster than the other solutions.

Comment: Ok, got it. The only downside to your solution is then that I can only deal with integers in X, right? If I would apply this in a Scikit-Learn context where most matrices X are float, this could be a problem.

Comment: That is correct.  Although that would mess up all of the solutions here.  I added an example of linking the unique values back to the results in my answer btw

Comment: Thanks, nice. I just tried the solution of @WarrenWeckesser with float values in X and it still worked. Why would it break down?